# How to get an element after it has changed in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I have pages with ads that display phone numbers after clicking on an item, but all these pages can have different formats and iterate over them all for a very long time. [Page example.](https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs/3385738/)

I try to find a clickable element on the page, save it and the parent element, click on the element and then find it through the parent element, but I can’t do it:

```py
>>> phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[contains(@class, "link-phone")]')
>>> phone.get_attribute('innerHTML')
'\n                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Показать телефон'
>>> phone_elem = phone.find_element_by_xpath('..')
>>> phone_elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')
'<a class="link-phone nowrap js-get-phone" href="javascript:void(0);">\n                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span>Показать телефон</a> '
>>> ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(phone).perform()
>>> sleep(0.5)
>>> phone.click()
>>> sleep(1.5)
>>> phone_elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 141, in get_attribute
    self, name)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.56)

>>>
```

Most likely, after clicking on an element the whole page changes. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the phone numbers you need to `scrollIntoView` the element first and then induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs/3385738/')
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p/b[text()='Условия:']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='link-phone nowrap js-get-phone']"))).click()
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//p/b[text()='Для связи с нами обращайтесь по номеру:']//following::p/b[contains(., '—')]")))])
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['+380 (93) 908 — 53 — 66 ', '+380 (93) — 103 — 19 — 77 ']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

After click `phone`, you can use the bellow `xpath` to get `innerHTML`:

```
//div[@id="job-description"]//p//b[contains(.,"+")]//ancestor::p
```

Use `.find_elements*` and extract them with iteration:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(phone).perform()
time.sleep(1)
phone.click()
time.sleep(1)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="job-description"]//p//b[contains(.,"+")]//ancestor::p')

for element in elements:
    print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```